# Using OpenCV's CMake module targets instead of including all libraries directly?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, target

Problem: I have a project which uses OpenCV.  I'm able to switch to what ever the latest version is if need be.   My project uses CMake. I currently integrate opencv like so:

```
# OPENCV package
find_package(OpenCV)
add_library(opencv INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(opencv
        INTERFACE
        ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(opencv
        INTERFACE
        ${OpenCV_LIBS})

add_executable(opencv_example example.cpp)

target_link_libraries(opencv_example 
    PRIVATE 
        opencv
)
```

I cannot find examples of OpenCV using explicit module dependency targets.  In order to not cruff up global includes unessessarily or leave naked variables laying around. I create an interface target for OpenCV and use this interface target instead of doing what [OpenCV CMake example recommends](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/example_cmake/CMakeLists.txt):

```
# Find OpenCV, you may need to set OpenCV_DIR variable
# to the absolute path to the directory containing OpenCVConfig.cmake file
# via the command line or GUI
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# Declare the executable target built from your sources
add_executable(opencv_example example.cpp)

# Link your application with OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(opencv_example ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

My question is it possible to just use OpenCV's module targets instead of having to bringing the whole kitchen sink along?

example (see module list [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/index.html)):

```
...

add_executable(opencv_example example.cpp)

target_link_libraries(opencv_example 
    PRIVATE
        opencv::core 
        opencv::video
        opencv::imgproc
)
```

thus I only get dependencies required for the modules I actually use. I looked through the OpenCV repository, but it is full of custom cmake macros and functions and It is difficult to see where a target is declared, let alone if it can be accessed from `find_package`.

Comment: I didn't test it, but did you try to specify components in the `find_package` command, like [stated here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4eb296655958e9241f43a7bd144d5e63759f6cea/cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in#L13): `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS viz)`?

Comment: @StanleyF. Huh no I didn't, I'll have to try that, That will probably fix my "everything and the kitchen sink" issues at the very least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While `opencv::module` doesn't work, if you use find_package, starting from at most OpenCV3.2 (it may have been available before) you can use targets like `opencv_module` for example with:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS core imgproc video)

add_executable(opencv_example example.cpp)

target_link_libraries(opencv_example 
    PRIVATE
        opencv_core 
        opencv_video
        opencv_imgproc
)
```

I found out these targets were exported here:https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8028#issuecomment-273419374

Comment: This is the issue tracking exported namespace support: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13117 . 

It seems likely to be part of OpenCV5, but unclear if it will be accepted into OpenCV4