# CMake Linker error : undefined reference to class

Tags: cmake, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a project with the following structur:

```
└── main/
    ├── CMakeLists.txt/
    │   └── src/
    │       └── main.cpp
    └── models/
        └── modelA/
            ├── src/
            │   └── h
            ├── lib
            └── CMakeLists.txt
```

`main/CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.0)
project(fiducial_marker_test)

IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
ENDIF()

MESSAGE("Build type: " ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}  -Wall -w  ")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -w ")

# Check C++11 or C++0x support
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/models/modelA)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/app)

add_executable(main ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/modules/modelA/src/)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE modelA)
```

and `main/models/modelA/CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.0)
project(libmodelA)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
file(GLOB SRC_FILE1 "./src*.c*")
file(GLOB SRC_FILE2 "./src/ED/*.c*")

include_directories(
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ED/
)
add_library(
    modelA SHARED
    ${SRC_FILE1}
    ${SRC_FILE2}
)
target_include_directories(modelA INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ED)

target_link_libraries(
    modelA
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

When i try to run cmake --build . from main/build it gives the following error:

```
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../app/main
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb9): undefined reference to `ModelA::ModelA(int, int, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:113: ../app/main] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:100: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I have tried different approaches to solve this problem but so far no luck. I believe is a linking problem?
I'm pretty new to cmake so any tips or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would set CMake verbose with `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` to check compilation commands

```
 set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

Then when you run *cmake --build*, you should be able to see something like `-lmodels/ModelA/libModelA.so` in linkage, this would mean that it is well done.

Secondly, upon inspecting this without checking the code, it appears that the constructor signature in ModelA.h might differ from that in ModelA.cc. Could this be the case?

Lastly, you could make your CMake configuration cleaner and more concise. When you use `find_package`, most of the time, you can link with the targets of those packages. These targets contain libraries and headers, so you wouldn't need to manually include and link only the necessary libraries. The same applies to your own libraries if you use `target_include_directories` with INTERFACE or PUBLIC. You can check OpenCV targets in [Using OpenCV's CMake module targets instead of including all libraries directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640570/using-opencvs-cmake-module-targets-instead-of-including-all-libraries-directly.) or another libs targets in [Conan center](https://conan.io/center). Doing this, `main/models/modelA/CMakeLists.txt` would be somehting like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.0)
project(libmodelA)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
file(GLOB SRC_FILE1 "./src*.c*")
file(GLOB SRC_FILE2 "./src/ED/*.c*")

add_library(
    modelA SHARED
    ${SRC_FILE1}
    ${SRC_FILE2}
)
target_include_directories(modelA INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ED)

target_link_libraries( modelA PRIVATE opencv_core)
```

Comment: thanks for the input! I appriciate the info, and help. I did figure out the error, which was caused by a typo in my `SRC_FILE1`.... The path should have been `"./src/*.c*"`...

Comment: It's true, I didn't notice it. Next time, you can try using `aux_source_directory(<dir> <variable>)`, which can help you avoid these errors.